# Find the least upper bound and greatest lower bound for { $x : \sin(x) \geq -1 $ }

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

I imagine that the lub is in $\Bbb{R }$

$\{x \in \Bbb{R} : \sin(x)\geq -1\}$

So since the sin(-1) is not a real number does that mean there isn't a greatest lower bound?

since the set would be unbounded does that mean there isn't a least upper bound?

Comment: What do you mean $\sin(-1)$ is not a real number?

Comment: $\sin(-1) \approx -0.84147$ is a fine real number, but that is not the question.  What numbers do you know that have a sine of $-1$?  There are a lot of them.

Comment: Why $\sin(-1)$ isn't a real number?

Comment: "ince the set would be unbounded does that mean there isn't a least upper bound?"  Yes, but you have to show the set is unbounded.  What *is* the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x \in \mathbb R$ we know $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ so for all $x\in \mathbb R, \sin x \ge -1$ and $\mathbb R \subset \{x|\sin x \ge -1\} $ and so $ \{x|\sin x \ge -1\} = \mathbb R$.

So you need to find the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of $\mathbb R$.

As $\mathbb R$ is neither bounded above (there is no real number, $k$ so that $k \ge x$ for *all* $x\in \mathbb R$) or below (there is no real number, $m$, so that $m \le x$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$) there are none.

Answer (score 0):

The LUB and GLB are $\infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively, because $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \mathrm{sin}(x) \ge -1$. The set the OP described is the entire set of real numbers.

Comment: $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not real numbers.  I'd say that most texts would say that that there are no LUB or GLB.